# NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia does not work

Tags: avplayer, ios10, app-transport-security

I have AVPlayer which use for play remote audio files.
According to last requeriments of Apple to ATS I have added NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia to info.plist.

But AVplayer can not load any file with prefix link HTTP. 
Do you know how can allow AvPlayer play link with HTTP (according to requirements of ATS)?

P.S. This functionality has to work on IOS 9 and iOS 10

Update:
it is my current plist
[image]

But, I am worry about apple review. What do you think? Does Apple allow send app to app Store with this keys?

Comment: Can you prove this is about app transport security and not about the AVPlayer?  e.g. see if you can request the file with `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: ...]`

Comment: Yes, I can.
For ios 9 it works ok,

Comment: Can you show your Info.plist?  That might help determine the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The plist file you've displayed doesn't contain the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` key.  The keys associated with your plist configuration above are `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`, respectively.  With `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` added, your plist should look like this:

[image: All arbitrary load keys]

(`NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` does not have an Xcode-friendly name in the plist file.) The reason it's working for iOS 9 is because `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` is all inclusive in iOS 9.  However, that key is [not supported in iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/NSAppTransportSecurity).  So at the end of the day, you're not actually configuring that property for iOS 10, the way you'd like.

As for whether Apple will accept such an app or not, [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW59) state:

> "Your use of certain App Transport Security (ATS) keys triggers additional App Store review for your app, and requires you to provide justification."

So it doesn't say that Apple *won't* accept the app.  But it appears that those keys do trigger further scrutiny of your app in the review process.

Comment: The docs says the AllowArbitraryLoads is supported on iOS 9+. The documentation clearly states that it is going to be ignored only if there is any other values provided under App Transport Security Settings. So, it seems if you only set the AllowArbitraryLoads to true and don't mention the other flags, it should work on all versions. That is of course if you don't mind having a fully non secure connection.